# Python Importing from Subdirectory

Tags: python

My file setup is like this:

- main/main.py
- main/sub/foo.py
- main/sub/bar.py

main has `import sub.foo`, foo has `import sub.bar`

`python main` works fine. But `python sub\foo` doesn't work, it doesn't recognize `sub` in `import sub.bar`. I want to be able to run `main` as well as `foo` by themselves, how can I do this properly in python3.4.1?

EDIT:
If I change foo to `import bar`, then `python main` says that it doesn't recognize bar in `import sub.foo`

Comment: `foo` should `import bar`, since it's in the same directory.

Comment: You never need to use backslashes for pathname separation.  Even MSDOS and Windows allow normal (forward) slashes.  By always using forward slashes, you won't accidentally specify a formfeed (\f) as you might be here.

Comment: wallyk, my mistake when writing this up. I always autocomplete with tab in my terminal and puts the correct slash in for me, so I don't usually use backslashes for pathname separation. Didn't know about the formfeed though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `python main.py` it works, because the directory of your input script is in the `main/` directory, and therefore all modules are found relative to that directory.

When running `foo.py` directly, there is no subdirectory named `sub` relative to the directory of `foo.py`.

One workaround is to `import bar` since it is in the same directory as foo. However this will fail in cases where `foo.py` and `bar.py` are in separate directories.

If you want to run `foo.py` directly, try adding the `main/` directory to your module search path. For example in `foo.py`:

```
# foo.py
import sys
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(foo_dir)
    sys.path.append(parent_dir)

import bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use __ init__.py (without spaces)

For example, on "main/main.py" use only:

```
#main.py    
import sub
```

Create a new file with this path "main/sub/__ init__.py"

```
#__init__.py
import foo
import bar
```